# Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo Ideapad s130

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am using fresh new Lenovo IdeaPad s130 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Everything is working fine except for the wifi connection (No Wi-Fi Adapter Found). The network controller is Realtek RTL8821CE.
Following advices on the web, I firstly installed following GIT https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
with no success.
Afterwards I installed https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
not working as well.
Kernel version is 5.0.0

I am an Ubuntu beginner and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command in your Terminal & Reboot your PC.

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

If you installed any Broadcom driver then uninstall it using the below command:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Maybe the above commands will help you get Wi-Fi in your PC.

Comment: This error is mainly occurred due to **The device is blocked by a platform Ideapad driver**. By running the `tee` command will help you unblock it. Now you can connect to the Wi-Fi connection. The Tee command will enable Wi-Fi on all Lenovo Ideapad Laptops!

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helped you solved the issue!! The Same command will help everyone to solve the Wi-Fi issue on Ideapad pc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I’m surprised this problem has not been described in other threads. Thank you, you saved me after long hours of struggling!