# Wi-fi not working on Lubuntu 20.04 with Lenovo Ideapad 130s (RTL8821CE)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lubuntu, lenovo

I'm recently new to Linux as the Lenovo Ideapad 130s-11igm I own was feeling sluggish on Windows 10, so I decided to install Lubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately the wifi chip (specifically RTL8821CE) doesn't work automatically with it. I've seen that this is a common problem with this wifi chip and have tried to follow many forum posts and guides that talk about it. I have tried to install using:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

but the install stopped at 
`Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...` and retrying the code gets me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,847 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 270688 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.8.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) over (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_12.8ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.8ubuntu1) over (12.8ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.25.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) over (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic_5.4.0-28.32_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic (5.4.0-28.32) over (5.4.0-28.32) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic (5.4.0-28.32) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-28-generic
   ...done.
Setting up dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up build-essential (12.8ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

I have also tried to blacklist using this post [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo Ideapad s130](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162713/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-ideapad-s130) but this does not work either. Any other post I seem to come across tends to lead either to the first method or another outdated one.

This is what I get back from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; rfkill list`

```
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
        Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

So after trying `sudo apt-get remove -y --purge man-db` I got in the terminal instead

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  x11-session-utils xbitmaps xinit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,847 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 270292 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.8.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) over (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_12.8ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.8ubuntu1) over (12.8ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.25.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) over (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic_5.4.0-28.32_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic (5.4.0-28.32) over (5.4.0-28.32) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic (5.4.0-28.32) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-28-generic
   ...done.
Setting up dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up build-essential (12.8ubuntu1) ...
```

And then rebooted, but wi-fi still isn't working.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; rfkill list`

Answer (score 1):

Reboot in the BIOS/UEFI and make sure that secure boot is off. You might have to set an administrator password for this.

Press F10 or F12 to save and exit

Once the machine has booted into Ubuntu, establish a temporary ethernet connection by plugging your cellphone into the USB port and settings >>> connections >>>> mobile hotspot and tethering >>> USB tethering.

Open a terminal.

Paste this line into the terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Press Enter

After it installs, reboot your computer. Your WiFi card should work now.

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to have fixed my issue 